# PHP email form buttons don't work in some email services?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, button

I'm trying to send emails to customers using php with some html in them, and I want them to include a form. It works in Gmail, but in other email providers the submit button doesn't work(clicking it does nothing). Is there something simple i can do to make the button work in all emails?

From other posts I think it might have something to do with the From: {$noreply_email}. But I don't know what to change it to or if that will solve everything. Could it be that the action link is still http and not https?

I could print a backup link in the email that they can copy, but I also want to send some values to the url it points to, and if I use a GET instead of POST it will make the $pass_var visible. I want it to be hidden to prove the email isn't fake.

How do other websites get their email buttons to work?

```
$pass_var = "notsosecretpassword55";
$noreply_email = "noreply.com";

$to = $primary_email; //the customer's email
$headers = "From: {$noreply_email} \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$subject = "Email Confirmation";

$body = '<html><body>

<p class="headings3">Please click the email confirmation button below to verify this email, as it is the primary means of communication that we will use.</p>

<form action="http://project.com/customer_validated.php" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0; display: inline;">
     <input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$primary_email.'">
     <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="'.$pass_var.'">
     <input type="submit" style="width: 200px;" name="validated" value="Confirm Email"/>
</form>

<p class="text">Thank you</p>                       

</body></html>';

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    //echo "<br/>EMAIL SENT";
} else { 
    //echo "<br/>EMAIL NOT SENT"; 
}
```

Comment: [Limitations of HTML email](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email) has forms in the "Do not use" column.

Comment: It says: **But interactive elements like Flash, JavaScript, or HTML forms won’t work in most email inboxes.**

Comment: Making the parameter hidden doesn't prevent faking it. It just makes it a little less obvious.